# Checking if a Ruby array's elements are included in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am trying to compare two Ruby arrays to verify that all of the first array's elements are included in the second one. (The reverse isn't needed.)

For example:

```
a = ["hello", "goodbye"]
b = ["hello", "goodbye", "orange"]
```

This should return true.

However, I can't figure out a method that will allow me to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are correct, thank you! My apologies for the duplicate. However, at this point I am unable to delete the question as there are already answers. Only a moderator can delete it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many ways are there to check the same :

```
a = ["hello", "goodbye"]
b = ["hello", "goodbye", "orange"]
(a - b).empty? # => true
a.all?{|i| b.include? i }
# => true

a = ["hello", "welcome"]
b = ["hello", "goodbye", "orange"]
(a - b).empty? # => false
a.all?{|i| b.include? i }
# => false
```

Answer (score 9):

Array set logic is nice here:

```
a & b == a
```

`a & b` produces a new array consisting of the elements that exist in both `a` and `b`. You can then test it against `a` to make sure that the cross section contains all of the elements of `a` itself. See the manual entry on [Array#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) for more details.

Comment: Note that this is no good if there are duplicate values. For example, `a=[1,1,2]; b=[1,2,3]; p a&b==a #=> false` since `a&b == [1,2]`. Per the duplicate question's answer, `(a-b).empty?` is perhaps a better bet.